# After running code, I received the Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-' error

Tags: java, quadratic

The problem is " Conversion = '-'". The source code is listed below. This is a program used to caculating the value of Coefficent A, B, and C based on the quadratic function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RootsTestHamer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variables
        double a, b, c;
        double r1, r2;
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner
    
        // prompts user to enter values for coefficents A, B, and C
        System.out.print("Enter the A coefficent:");
         a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the B coefficent:");
         b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the C coefficent:");
         c = input.nextDouble();

        // calucating roots
        r1 = ( Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c));
        r1 = (-b + (Math.sqrt(r1))) / (2 * a);

        r2 = ( Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c));
        r2 = (-b - (Math.sqrt(r2))) / (2 * a);

        // calls the method and determines # of roots
        double r = roots (a, b, c);

        // if statements and display
        if (r > 1) {
            System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
            System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r1);
            System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r2);
        }

        else if (r == 1) 
        {
        System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
        System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r1);
        }

        else if (r == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c);
        }
}

        //user - defined root method
    public static double roots(double a, double b, double c) {
        double roots = 0;

        //number of roots
        if (Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c) > 0) {
            roots = 2;
        }
        else if (Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c) == 0) {
            roots = 1;
        }
        else if (Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c) < 0) {
            roots = 0;
        }       

            return roots;
    }
}
```

I attempted to run the code. After entering the value 1, 2,3 for coefficents A, B,and C, the code returned Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

Comment: does it give you a line number?

Comment: It says java:56

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your print statements:

```
    System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
    ...
    System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
    ...
    System.out.printf("%.0f, %.of, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c);
```

I think you have a typo in all of these: `%.of` should be `%.0f` as they are elsewhere in the string.

Also the last print statement needs to have all four arguments `a, b, c, r` like the first two do.

---

In general, it is always helpful to look at the stack trace java provides on an error to see what line of the code you wrote is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your messages, the second parameter "of" instead of "0f", and r == 0 print statement requires 4 parameters you have only given 3. Check below.

```
if (r > 1) {
            System.out.printf("%.0f, %.0f, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
            System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r1);
            System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r2);
        }

        else if (r == 1)
        {
            System.out.printf("%.0f, %.0f, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
            System.out.printf("\n\tR1 = %.2f",r1);
        }

        else if (r == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%.0f, %.0f, and %.0f coefficients have %.0f real roots:",a, b, c, r);
        }
```